# Auto-delete spam

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned, spam

Nowadays, there is a big wave of questions from black-magic spammers. What if there could be an option like `auto-delete user` or `prevent-spammer` as he tries to post phrases like *"black-magic, +91 (number), love, marriage"*, etc. (and a few more can be gathered) in his spam. I know that mods delete such user accounts at the instant when they see. But, is there any other way to prevent them from posting or gather a few more phrases because, mods are not around sometime.

I also know that it takes a bunch of algorithm add-ups to the engine's clockwork. But, the cloud of spam has surrounded SE (I don't know about other sites) and there are atleast 5 spams per day flooding the active list (in the front page). *I don't think this would be good in MSO*

Comment: +1 for [tag:status-planned] first question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already is a feature like this, known as blacklisting (not available to mods). SE has been notified, they're trying to deal with it.

Comment: Ahh... I get it. BTW, I didn't know that mods have something like [tag:status-planned]. Cool ;-)

Comment: I really hope we will soon come to terms with that spam issue!